# Time complexity of this nested for loop

Tags: java, time-complexity

```
for (int i = 0; i < this.tiles.length * this.tiles.length; i++) {
        int row = i / this.tiles.length;
        int col = i % this.tiles.length;
        for (int j = i+1; j < this.tiles.length * this.tiles.length; j++) {
            int compareRow = j / this.tiles.length;
            int compareCol = j % this.tiles.length;
            if(this.tiles[compareRow][compareCol] < this.tiles[row][col]) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
```

I have to calculate the time complexity of this function, i first thought it was ~n*n-1 but i'm pretty sure that's actually wrong. Can anybody explain what the time complexity of this piece of code is?

Comment: If the loops were like `for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) { for (int j = i+1; j < n; ++j) { } }`, what would the complexity be? Then, why is this different?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 for loops each iterating (tiles.length*tiles.length) times . So it is :

Number of times of comparison :

- First set of  comparison(i=0) : tiles.length<sup>2</sup>
- Second set of comparison (i=1): tiles.length<sup>2</sup> -1
- .
- .
- Last set of comparision(i=tiles.length<sup>2</sup> -1 ) : 1

= (   ( tiles.length<sup>2</sup> ) + ( tiles.length<sup>2</sup> -1 ) + ( tiles.length<sup>2</sup> - 2) ....... + 2 + 1  )

= 
**O(tiles.length<sup>3</sup>)**

Comment: You can have 2 for loops iterating `tl * tl` times, and it can be `O(tl^2)`. The key point is that they're nested loops.

Comment: O(n) is about finding the worst case. Here we just have 2 nested for loops and that is O(n^2) (or to be more on the code: O(tiles.length^2))

Answer (score 0):

```
 for (int i = 0; i < this.tiles.length * this.tiles.length; i++) { //O(n)
        int row = i / this.tiles.length; 
        int col = i % this.tiles.length; 
        for (int j = i+1; j < this.tiles.length * this.tiles.length; j++) { //O(n^2) it's squared because there are two loops
            int compareRow = j / this.tiles.length; //n +
            int compareCol = j % this.tiles.length; //+ n
            if(this.tiles[compareRow][compareCol] < this.tiles[row][col]) {  //n
                count++; 
            }
        }
    }
```

> O(n^2 + n) == O(n^2)

The way I was taught was that for every loop it's O(n) so, a nested loop would naturally be O(n^2), and with every condition or operation would be `n + n ..nth` which is where O(n^2 + n) = O(n^2)

Hope that helped a bit.

checkout the resource below for a more depth explanation.

Resources:

- https://rob-bell.net/2009/06/a-beginners-guide-to-big-o-notation/

Comment: You gave the resource and in it there is this sentence as an example for O(n^2) with two nested for loops: "This is common with algorithms that involve nested iterations over the data set. Deeper nested iterations will result in O(N3), O(N4) etc." In this given code there are only 2 nested iterations over the data set.